# How to share videos from Ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, video, phone, sharing

Hi can anyone help me here, when I take a photo on my BQ 4.5 I have options to share from my gallery. When I take a video I can't work out how to share the same options are not available when watching the video.

I like to take video notes, to help remind me of things, I have found that I now use my girlfriends phone more than my own, as with that (HTC android) I just shoot the video straight away I can share on google drive and view it from anywhere & on any device...
Really shouldn't be using someone else's phone when I have my own, there must be an easier way!

Hope someone can help.

~~Edit~~ Ok so worked out you can't share video from "media player" when viewing videos but you can through "photo roll" (or gallery before hitting play) although the video is just a black screen with white play arrow so it's hard to know which video you are sharing. Also it only appears to share through telegram, anything else I can download to share it? I want the video myself on my desktop (iMac) can't work out how to get this at all.

Answer (score 2):

For sharing videos with dropbox you can use `udropcabin`. while downloading from udropcabin you have many options for sharing like Notes and Dekko app. by using Dekko you can mail yourself :).
For transferring files and other data you can `wifi transfer` app.