# What is easiest way to share on Ubuntu touch (bq aquaris 4.5)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, aquaris

Hi I posted [before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625291/how-to-share-videos-from-ubuntu-touch) asking best way to share videos but didn't get much help. I am now finding it hard to share images + everything else. I have been very busy in personal/work life this last few months and haven't taken the time to explore this phone right, at the minute I am just using it a a phone not a smart phone, all I do is call and text. I find it hard to do the most mundane tasks that I could do in seconds on a Android.

When I look at an image in gallery, if I hit share I have the options of Facebook, messaging, twitter or telegram. I want to have the image on my own e-mail or desktop, I don't want it on social media. Is there any app I can download. Google drive would be easiest I think.

I also have't a clue how to transfer my images/video/etc onto my SD card, any help here?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to share videos from Ubuntu touch?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/625291/how-to-share-videos-from-ubuntu-touch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Dekko for email or uDropCabin for Dropbox.

Comment: And use File Manager for transfer files. (Using your admin password)

Answer (score 2):

use Dekko for sending it via email
[image: dekko for using google services and other imap and smtp accounts]

use **Wifi Transfer** App from ubuntu store from transfering data to your laptop.

[image: using wifi transfer in ubunti]

however for ubuntu you can use by plugging usb to your computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily copy pictures and videos from your phone to your desktop by plugging it via USB cable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mhall, my desktop is a mac :( so when I connect USB to my phone it only charges, I have never been able to connect it to transfer.